# Two instances of Widget Only One Instance Working

Tags: javascript, widget

I have a widget that only works with one instance.

The problem I have is that if I have one instance of the widget on a page it works fine. If I have more than one instance on the page, only one instance works. The second instance does not work...

you can check this page for an example http://fullylinked.com/advert.php

From my troubleshooting, I have noticed the following
1. The placement ID of the second instance is not passed to the script.
2. Even if the default placement ID is used, I get an error saying
    "Uncaught ReferenceError: jsonpCallback is not defined". 
Unfortunately the jsonpCalback is defined because the first script works..

Please here are my code..
The Widget...

```
<script placementID = "37"     src="placement.js" type="text/javascript">    </script> 
<div id="widget-container_37"></div>
```

---- Second instance below this line -------

```
<script placementID = "36" src="placement.js" type="text/javascript"></script><div id="widget-container_36"></div>
```

NOW HERE IS THE .JS file

```
(function() {
 // Localize jQuery variable
var jQuery;

/******** Load jQuery if not present *********/
if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery !== '1.4.2') {
var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
script_tag.setAttribute("src",
    "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js");
if (script_tag.readyState) {
  script_tag.onreadystatechange = function () { // For old versions of IE
      if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
          scriptLoadHandler();
      }
  };
} else {
  script_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
}
// Try to find the head, otherwise default to the documentElement
(document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
} else {
// The jQuery version on the window is the one we want to use
jQuery = window.jQuery;
main();
}

/******** Called once jQuery has loaded ******/
function scriptLoadHandler() {
// Restore $ and window.jQuery to their previous values and store the
// new jQuery in our local jQuery variable
jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
// Call our main function
main(); 
}

/******** Our main function ********/
function main() { 
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    /******* Load CSS *******/
   /** var css_link = $("<link>", { 
        rel: "stylesheet", 
        type: "text/css", 
        href: "style.css" 
    });
    css_link.appendTo('head');  
   /**** get host name ***/
  var site_name = window.location.hostname;


    /****** get user ID******/
  var this_js_script = $('script[src*=placement]'); // get file name..*/
  var placementID = this_js_script.attr('placementID');  
  /**var placementID = document.getElementById("adblabla_2").getAttribute("placementID");**/
  if (typeof placementID === "undefined" ) {
     var placementID = '23';

  }

    /******* Load HTML *******/

  $.ajax({
        url: 'processors/processor.php?placementID='+placementID,
        data: {name: 'Chad', site: site_name},
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'callback',
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',
        success: function(data){
           //alert(placementID);
           $('#widget-container_'+placementID).html(data.message);

        }
    });


});
  function jsonpCallback(data){
 $('#widget-container_2').text(data.message);

 }

}

})();
```

Comment: Its calling twice the same main function, you need to either have uniqe function names for  `main()`, or encapsulate it somehow.

Comment: Please  I am a novice in JavaScript and I only wrote this code by following a tutorial I saw on the web.  Please is it possible to provide  a code that works? PLEASE..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is another then I thought, your code is already encapsulated, so its not calling twice the same main function, but it finds twice the same script tag, and thus gets the wrong parameter I think.
http://www.2ality.com/2014/05/current-script.html
Well you can try this code:

```
(function () {
    // Localize jQuery variable
    var jQuery,
        //get current script
        currentScript = document.currentScript || (function () {
            var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
            return scripts[scripts.length - 1];
        })();

    /******** Load jQuery if not present *********/
    if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery !== '1.4.2') {
        var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
        script_tag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        script_tag.setAttribute("src",
            "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js");
        if (script_tag.readyState) {
            script_tag.onreadystatechange = function () { // For old versions of IE
                if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
                    scriptLoadHandler();
                }
            };
        } else {
            script_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
        }
// Try to find the head, otherwise default to the documentElement
        (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
    } else {
// The jQuery version on the window is the one we want to use
        jQuery = window.jQuery;
        main();
    }

    /******** Called once jQuery has loaded ******/
    function scriptLoadHandler() {
// Restore $ and window.jQuery to their previous values and store the
// new jQuery in our local jQuery variable
        jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
// Call our main function
        main();
    }

    /******** Our main function ********/
    function main() {
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            /******* Load CSS *******/
            /** var css_link = $("<link>", {
        rel: "stylesheet",
        type: "text/css",
        href: "style.css"
    });
             css_link.appendTo('head');
             /**** get host name ***/
            var site_name = window.location.hostname;


            /****** get user ID******/
            var this_js_script = $(currentScript); // get file name..*/
            var placementID = this_js_script.attr('placementID');
            /**var placementID = document.getElementById("adblabla_2").getAttribute("placementID");**/
            if (typeof placementID === "undefined") {
                var placementID = '23';

            }

            /******* Load HTML *******/

            $.ajax({
                url: 'processors/processor.php?placementID=' + placementID,
                data: {name: 'Chad', site: site_name},
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonp: 'callback',
                success: function (data) {
                    //alert(placementID);
                    $('#widget-container_' + placementID).html(data.message);

                }
            });


        });
        function jsonpCallback(data) {
            $('#widget-container_2').text(data.message);

        }

    }

})();
```

PS: its always very useful when you build up a testcase on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback. I finally got it to work by not defining the name of the JsonCallback function.. But now there is another problem..the parameter placementID which I pass to the script is only seen in the first instance. In the second instance, it is always returned as undefined which forces it to take the default value. Can you help with this?

Comment: hehe, I guess I was on wrong track then, very good you fixed it.

Comment: hahaahhaaa.. Yeah, I was just lucky.. so can you help with capturing the right placementID into the script for every instance?

Comment: I edited the code I made, and removed the  `jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',` not sure if thats the correct one.
I thought your code does not get the placement id, so thats what I had fixed. Although I am not sure if it works.

Comment: Yes you removed the right thing... it works now...thanks